# How can I install Ubuntu Server on an PowerPC Mac?

Tags: installation, mac-mini

I have an original mac mini (pre-late 2005 model) that I bought at an auction. The computer was completely wiped clean. There were no disks given with the computer. I turn the computer on and it loads a gray screen with a folder in the center, blinking with the question mark and smiley face.

Here's what's I've tried.

I burned Ubuntu on to a cd using another computer and loaded it into the mini. I reset the computer and waited for the cd to load. The cd never loaded. I took the cd out and restarted the computer.

I made a USB install drive, following the instructions on Ubuntu's website. I turned off the mac mini. I inserted the USB into the mac mini. I turned on the mac mini while holding down the alt key. A purple screen comes on with two buttons, one for 'refresh' and one for 'next'. There are no other buttons or items on the screen (excluding the mouse).

My question: How do I install Ubuntu on this mac mini?

Comment: Have you tried holding down the 'c' key when turning on the computer (to boot to the CD drive)?

Comment: Yes I tried that. It's not loading it.

Comment: I just updated the question. USB install doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: Just to be sure - Are you downloading the PPC image, not the Intel one?

Comment: Ubuntu server version doesn't make any distinction except for 64bit and 32bit. I dl'd the 32bit.

Comment: This question should be moved over to Ask Ubuntu. It's only a "Mac question" because it happens to refer to a no-longer-supported (PPC-based) Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install i386 software on a PowerPC CPU. That's a completely different architecture, with a different instruction set -- they're not compatible.

Ubuntu has dropped official support for PowerPC a long time ago, but there are still community builds available. A good starting point is the [Ubuntu Power PC FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ).

Comment: This is a follow-up question to the awesome answer. Any download available for an Ubuntu Server?I see the download for Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat. Does that include a server?

Comment: Nevermind the comment. I found the answer. http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/lucid/release/